Identifying SMD diode - markings ST e3 G (next line) DUK (next line) G3 635 (or b35)
I am trying to identify the following diode. I can see it says DUK G3 but am unsure on the last part, if it’s meant to be 63S or b35 or something like that. I’ve tried multiple Google searches and can’t find anything on it.


Can you caliper the length and width so we know what package size it is?

The The ultimate SMD marking codes database shows the marking code DUK is SMAJ12A from SGS-Thomson Microelectronics with the description:

Transient voltage supressor
Vrwm=12V, Vbr=13.3..14.7V, 20.1A, 400W(1ms)

The datasheet confirms the marking code:

And shows the layout of the device marking:


Many thanks !, the location in the circuit would be correct for transient voltage suppression. As customer decided it was a good idea to bridge the circuit board fuse, which in turn vaporised some traces and killed this diode.
